# "worker_processes" directive is not allowed nginx

Tags: nginx, akka, config

I need to create nginx.conf file with such routes: /assets - static files, /akka - for hello-world akka webapp, /* - default page. My default.conf file looks like this:

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    upstream hello-akka{
        server localhost:9000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /akka {
        proxy_pass http://hello-akka;
        }

        location /assets {
        root /var/www;
        }   
    }
}
```

Every time I restart nginx service I get these error messages:

```
nginx: [emerg] "worker_processes" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I checked the structure of the file itself and I can't figure out what is wrong. Even when I delete this line I get the same "directive is not allowed" error but for other lines like pid, events and so on.
So how can I fix such error?

Comment: Your `default.conf` file is explicitly included in `/etc/nginx.conf`. Particularly, in the `http` block. So, everything you put in `default.conf` is already in the `http` context. You should either move (merge) everything except the `server` block from `default.conf` to `/etc/nginx.conf`, or remove these lines of configuration from `default.conf`.

Comment: @IvanTsirulev thanks. It has fixed my problem!

Comment: This definitely helps. In Ubuntu 22, the location of the configuration files is /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: The gunicorn docs should call this out. I imagine a lot of people find their way here when trying to use the nginx config provided here: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html#nginx-configuration

Answer (score 27):

Put that directive at the top of the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` instead of `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`.

The `worker_processes` directive is valid only at the top level of the configuration.

Now it comes by default in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Answer (score -3):

A simple solution that worked for me.

Just add `server` section in the ngnix.conf and remove all the content like

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /akka {
    proxy_pass http://hello-akka;
    }

    location /assets {
    root /var/www;
    }   
}
```

Comment: This fixes the problem but applies drastic changes to the config